# Potentially dangerous input ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

.NET 4.0
VS 2012
IIS 7

I have an app that takes in email addresses on various pages, and I'm finding that users are copy/pasting directly into a few inputs and it's triggering the error mentioned in the title, here's an example.

```
"blah blah" <blah@blah.com>
```

Obviously the brackets are triggering the problem.  I realize I can simply switch the validation to 2.0, but I would prefer not doing that, so here are my question(s).

- Is there a way to have the runtime react better?  When this is encountered, instead of throwing up an uber scary page it treats it as an input error and displays a message to the user (in the general case)  For example, in scenario I'm speaking of, I could display an error message about < and > not being allowed in email addresses.  I like the protection, but I dislike the idea that the 'oops' page is shown everytime someone enters input that's potentially dangerous.
- If I were to relax the validation:

  - Can I do it on a per page basis?  I don't believe so, but I'm asking for completeness
  - What tools does ASP.NET give me to protect myself against these types of issues manually?  I really don't want to get into the game of writing stuff to look over the input for potentially dangerous things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can relax your validation on a per page basis by putting ValidateRequest="false" in the page heading.

You can then use a regular expression to validate the email address, like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid e-mail address" 
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />
```

For other controls you could use the regular expression "^[^<>]+$" to check for angle brackets.  In reality, you don't need to worry about "potentially dangerous" user input unless you're outputting it to the client (HTML / JavaScript), or you're including it in an SQL statement.

Alternatively, you could try to write a page level error handler in your page or an application level error handler in Global.asax.

Page level error handling: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed577840(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed577840%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Application level error handling:
 [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This page gives some useful info about disabling request validation in ASP.NET:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I've gone ahead and marked this as the answer, but what I was really looking for was something like so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx.  It's a library from MS that can be used to help mitigate XSS attacks.